# Hexadecimal Calculator Features. What do you want?

Tags: hex, calculator

I plan on making a Hex Calculator one of these weekends for my android phone. I would like to put it up as a free application on the android market when I'm done. As a programmer, what do you think are some valuable features that I should consider?

Comment: You should ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

- Convert to/from decimal and binary
- AND / OR / NOT / XOR / 2s Complement
- Basic arithmetic ( plus,minus, multiply, divide)
- Multiple memories

Answer (score 1):

1. Conversion between hex, binary and decimal would be nice
2. Showing current date and time in hex
3. Coloring of inputs like (FF, 00, 00) as RGB values
4. Usual arithmetic
5. Stack based calculation
6. Registers for saving of values for some future time
7. Defining variables for easier re-use

Too much? Doable?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious adding and subtracting hex color values, the next hex operation I perform the most is averaging two (or even an array of) hex color values.  Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

add octal to the conversions

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: No really, a hex calculator should have octal conversions as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

overflow flag for assembly programing.

when ever there is a arithmetic operation of two numbers (in two's compliment mode), this flag is raised  when calculations fall out of range.